# Is there a Stack Exchange site for those wishing to participate in activities like Code for Venezuela?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

For example,

> Code for Venezuela is a 501 (c) (3) non-profit organization dedicated to bringing together technologists and innovators who care about Venezuela leveraging their talent and network to solve the most pressing needs of the country.

Suppose you wanted to work on behalf of Haiti, or Ukraine, or to aid in efforts against some disease. Where would you go looking for advice on Stack Exchange?

Comment: Non off the sites in the network act as a "job" board so if you're looking for a place to match your skill or ability with demand from disaster areas then you're out of luck.

Comment: What would the specific question be?

Comment: If we assume that "aid against some disease" has a medical science aspect a focused question on that topic might fit on [Medical Science](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)  but study their help and/or ask on their meta first.

Comment: @rene: Not exactly like a job board but you're close. A place announcing initiatives intended to provide computerised support for disaster, food shortage or epidemic areas.

Comment: That doesn't fit the goal of any SE site which wants to be a knowledge base for generation to come. Not much value in 2028 to read about an announcement that was only valid in 2022. Use facebook, instagram, twitter instead, that are networks build for that purpose, to be social.